# MATLAB-C interfacing: Access violation error on memcpy

Tags: c++, matlab, memcpy

I am trying to connect a C++ code with MATLAB. I simply want to copy a variable into a MATLAB-array using memcpy. But that results in Access violation error:

Unhandled exception at 0x009a1043 in MATLAB_C_connection.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Here's the C++ code I'm using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include "engine.h"
#include "coupled_cfd.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "mclmcr.h"
#include "mclmcrrt.h"
#include "mclcppclass.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "libmx.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libmat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libmex.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeng.lib")
#define  BUFSIZE 256


int main()
{
    Engine *ep;
    mxArray *x = NULL, *result = NULL;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE+1];
    double var[1] = {5};

    double *destination;

    ep = engOpen(NULL); //ep = engOpen("\0");
    x = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

    destination = mxGetPr(x);
    memcpy(destination, var, sizeof(double));

    //engPutVariable(ep, "X", x);
    //engEvalString(ep, "D = X");
    //engEvalString(ep, "plot(X,D)");
    //engEvalString(ep, "close;");

    std::cout << var[0];
    system("PAUSE");
    mxDestroyArray(x);
    engClose(ep);
    return 1;   
}
```

The strange thing is that if I use &destination in memcpy, the code compiles and works, but that is not exactly what I want. Instead, I want the value of the variable "var" to be copied into the array "x".
Could anyone help me please. 
Many thanks,
//Soheil

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `var` is a constant pointer to the array, so the value of `var` is the address of its first element. Are you saying you want to copy the address of the first element into `destination`?

Answer (score 0):

x is array type. To get a pointer to the location of a value inside the matrix array you have to specify it.

Try `destination = mxGetPr(x[0]);` instead.